# Custom Validation fails because params are nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend

i have a Class called SocialNetwork with an url and an enum of social_networks. I have a regexp validation of the url depending on the social network selected, but it fails if the record is being created due to the fact that both params are nil.

```
class SocialNetwork < ApplicationRecord
  REGEXP = {
    facebook: %r{\Ahttps://www.facebook.com/.+\z},
    twitter: %r{\Ahttps://twitter.com/.+\z},
    linkedin: %r{\Ahttps://www.linkedin.com/in/.+\z},
    github: %r{\Ahttps://github.com/.+\z},
    instagram: %r{\Ahttps://www.instagram.com/.+\z},
    youtube: %r{\Ahttps://www.youtube.com/.+\z},
    tiktok: %r{\Ahttps://www.tiktok.com/.+\z},
    twitch: %r{\Ahttps://www.twitch.tv/.+\z},
    onlyfans: %r{\Ahttps://onlyfans.com/.+\z}
  }.freeze

  belongs_to :user

  validates :url, presence: true
  validates :app, presence: true

  validates :app, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
  validate :url_match_regexp

  enum app: { facebook: 0, twitter: 1, instagram: 2, linkedin: 3, youtube: 4, tiktok: 5,
              twitch: 6, onlyfans: 7, github: 8 }

  private

  def url_match_regexp
    errors.add(:url, 'is not valid') unless url.match(REGEXP[app])
  end
end
```

How can i test `url_match_regexp` before the record being created?

Comment: you can use `before_save` hook and call the checking method, `before_save :check_url_regexp`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: you can also call `url_match_regexp` validation when `app` is provided `validate :url_match_regexp, if: -> { app.present? }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want run validate when params are not nil, try this:

```rb
validates :app, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }, if: -> { app.present? }
validate :url_match_regexp, if: -> { app.present? && url_match_regexp.present? }
```

btw,

- `url.match(REGEXP[app])` won't return `boolean` => use `match?`
- `url` can be any type (example: number) => use `to_s`
- `app` can be present but it may not in enum list => should check `app` included in enum list

```rb
validates :app, presence: true, inclusion: { in: apps.values }
...
url.to_s.match?(REGEXP[app])
```

Answer (score 1):

You already verify that `app` and `url` must be present in these lines

```
validates :url, presence: true
validates :app, presence: true
```

and if they are not present, then there will be a useful error message.

This means it is would be totally fine to just ignore those cases in your custom validation method, because the user would have to fix the missing `app` and `url` first anyway.

I would fix this problem by just changing the validation method to this:

```
def url_match_regexp
  return unless app && url

  errors.add(:url, 'is not valid') unless url.match?(REGEXP[app])
end
```